# Apply custom function to magento Admin edit form

Tags: magento-2.1, backend, adminform

I have made custom module in admin for add/edit and delete.

For a particular field (example email ) in the edit form, I want to show HTML instead of an edit input field.

For example, I am saving values in the database for column email as a@a.com,b@b.com.

When a user edits that form I want to show custom HTML like below

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>EMail</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a@ac.om</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b@b.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

for applying the custom function to edit field where should I do changes, below is code of Main.php

Vendor/Magento/Block/Adminhtml/Trulookadmin/Edit/Tab/Main.php

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    /* @var $model \Obl\Trulookadmin\Model\BlogPosts */
    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('formadmin');

    $isElementDisabled = false;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();

    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('page_');

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Item Information')]);

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id']);
    }


    $fieldset->addField(
        'email',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'email',
            'label' => __('EMail'),
            'title' => __('EMail'),

            'disabled' => true
        ]
    );
```

Comment: You want the show only details like table instead of Input field, Right?

Comment: yes ...........

Comment: I have added answer, Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/304489/59677

Answer (score 0):

I have added code in your block file, Check this.

```
protected $_rendererFieldset;

public function __construct(
    -------------
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
    -------------
)
{
    ------------
    $this->_rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
    ------------
}

protected function _prepareForm()
{
    /* @var $model \Obl\Trulookadmin\Model\BlogPosts */
    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('formadmin');

    $isElementDisabled = false;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();

    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('page_');

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Item Information')]);

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id']);
    }


    $fieldset->addField(
        'html',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'html',
            'label' => __('EMail'),
            'title' => __('EMail')
        ]
    )->setRenderer($this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::testtable.phtml'));
```

You need to create a PHTML file in your module for Table HTML and render it on your field in your form.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: will i get email values in testtable.phtml file

Comment: You can create another function in the same block file and get values in PHTML file like <td><?= $block->getEmail(); ?></td>